# Spring Integration : How to retrieve header values in Aggregator class

Tags: spring-integration

How to retrieve header values when I combine two different messages using Aggregator. I have two messages with different header but with same UUID. When I combine these two messages using aggregator with uuid, I do not find a way to retrieve header in custom Aggregator class. does it mean header values are lost? Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

The aggregated message gets a UNION of all the headers. However if there is a conflict, the aggregator doesn't know which value to use so the header is dropped, with this debug message...

```
logger.debug("Excluding header '" + keyToRemove + "' upon aggregation due to conflict(s) "
        + "in MessageGroup with correlation key: " + group.getGroupId());
```

If you need to retain the values, they need to be in different headers.